# Executing Commands to External Linux Server via SharpSSH

Tags: c#, ssh

I am trying to communicate with a remote Linux machine using the Tamir.SharpSSH library. I have been able to establish the connection, and submit the commands. However, I need to press enter twice to see the response from the server.

This is the code I am using:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Tamir.SharpSsh;

namespace SshMultipleConsoles
{
    static class Program
    {

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        AllocConsole();
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Form1 x = new Form1();
        Application.Run(x);
        x.Close();

        SshExec ssh = null;
        SshStream ssh2 = null;
        try
        {
            Console.Write("-Connecting...");
            ssh2 = new SshStream(host, username, password);

            ssh2.Prompt = "\n";
            ssh2.RemoveTerminalEmulationCharacters = true;
            Console.Write(ssh2.ReadResponse());

            while (true)
            {
                string command = Console.ReadLine();

                if (command == "exit")
                    break;

                ssh2.Write(command);
                ssh2.ReadResponse();   // UPDATE
                string data = ssh2.ReadResponse();
                Console.Write(data);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        if (ssh2 != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnecting...");
            ssh2.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("OK");
        }

        Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
    }
}
```

}

Here is the output I am getting:

[image]

As you can see, I type the "ls" command, and press enter. Nothing returns. I press enter again, and I see the command that was submitted along with the files in the folder. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

I found out that if I run the ssh2.ReadResponse() command twice, this does not occur. This is telling me that when I run the ls command, I get back 2 responses? However, when I run "cd.." this command stalls (since I believe there is no second response). I am not sure how this is working.

Comment: Add a line feed to the command as in `ssh.Write(command + "\n");` ?

Comment: That did not help. It's hard to explain the result via comment.